# Creating a button with a loop does not create individual labels

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In my save menu, I've added the option to create as many save files as the player wants, and the buttons indicating each save should appear on start-up with their corresponding number, however the function that I use to create the individual buttons, doesn't work as intended.

Assuming `saveamount = 9`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def newsave():
    global saveamount #this is 0 by default
    saveamount = saveamount + 1
    savecountdoc = open("saves/savecount.txt", "w+")
    savecountdoc.write(str(saveamount))
    Button(scrollable_frame, text="Save " + str(saveamount), width="53", height="5").pack()

def savespack():
    savelabelcount = 0
    savebuttontext = StringVar()
    for i in range(saveamount):
        savelabelcount = savelabelcount + 1
        print(savelabelcount) #prints 1-9
        savebuttontext.set("Save " + str(savelabelcount))
        Button(scrollable_frame, textvariable=savebuttontext, width="53", height="5").pack()

def savefiles():
    global backbutton
    global scrollable_frame
    playbutton.place_forget()
    backbutton = Button(main, text="Back", width ="56", command=startscreenback)
    backbutton.grid(row="0", column="0")
    savesframe = ttk.Frame(main)
    savesframecanvas = Canvas(savesframe)
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(savesframe, orient="vertical", command=savesframecanvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(savesframecanvas)
    scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda e: savesframecanvas.configure(
            scrollregion=savesframecanvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )
    savespack()
    newsavebutton = Button(scrollable_frame, text="New Save", width="53", height="5", command=newsave).pack()
    savesframecanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
    savesframecanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    savesframe.place(x="0", y="50")
    savesframecanvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

main = Tk()
main.title("Fruit Clicker")
main.geometry("400x350+300+100")
playbutton = Button(main, text="Play", width="40", height="3", command=savefiles)
playbutton.place(x="60", y="100")
main.mainloop()
```

This creates the correct amount of buttons, but they all say "Save 9" instead of "Save (1-9)". I assume this is because the loop is creating one big group of buttons but im not sure. How do I make the buttons display the correct numbers.

Tell me if I need to add any more code, thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem, a little more description or code like when is `newsave()` executed would be appreciated.

Comment: You have not given any `text` option to the button, why? Its better to use `text="Save " + str(savelabelcount)` rather than `textvariable`.

Comment: @Mayank I cant give a working replica without adding another 50-60 lines of code, so ill try to explain it. newsave() is called from a button in window

Comment: @Mayank I just edited it see if you can run that

Comment: I tried replicating with your old code and it works just fine: https://imgur.com/a/69soED9

Comment: Have you tried moving `StringVar()` inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a single `StringVar` and using it for all your buttons, which mean all will have same text. You have to create new `StringVar` for each button, so move it inside the loop.

```
for i in range(saveamount):
    savebuttontext = StringVar() # Create a variable each time
    savelabelcount = savelabelcount + 1
    print(savelabelcount) #prints 1-9
    savebuttontext.set("Save " + str(savelabelcount)) # Change it
    Button(scrollable_frame, textvariable=savebuttontext, width=53, height=5).pack() # Use it
```

Though I don't recommend this approach, as its more easy to just use `text` option, which will get rid of having to store the `StringVar` somewhere(or its just pointless to use one), like:

```
for i in range(saveamount):
    savelabelcount = savelabelcount + 1
    print(savelabelcount) #prints 1-9
    text = "Save " + str(savelabelcount)
    Button(scrollable_frame, text=text, width=53, height=5).pack()
```

A more pythonic approach might be to change `text` to:

```
text = f'Save {savelabelcount}'
```